# QComboBox Get The Varient When "currentIndexChanged(int)" Emitted

Tags: c++, qt

I am having difficulty finding documentation on this or an example.

Could someone concretely show me how to access the QVariant of the currently selected index in a QComboBox

```
 QComboBox * combo = new QComboBox();
 combo->addItem("Bla1", QVariant(1));
 combo->addItem("Bla2", QVariant(2));
 combo->addItem("Bla3", QVariant(3));
 combo->addItem("Bla4", QVariant(4));
 connect(combo, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, slot(HANDLEITMAN(int))
```

And of course else where in the source

```
 void TheCooler::HANDLEITMAN(int index)
 {
      //What do I do with index?
      //sender()?
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make `combo` a member of `TheCooler`, or otherwise put `HANDLEITMAN` in a class which has `combo` as a member.  Unless it's available to `TheCooler::HANDLEITMAN` somehow you can't get the data, and this is the logical way to do it. Then it's just

```
 void TheCooler::HANDLEITMAN(int index)
 {
      QVariant data = combo->itemData(index);
 }
```

Comment: I think this may be the best approach, even though I'm very against member variables when dealing with structured environments (Layouts->Widgets->Layouts->etc...)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to make combo a member of the class `TheCooler`, you can use the `sender()` function that returns a pointer to the `QObject` that sent the triggering signal (in this case, `currentIndexChanged(int)`).

```
void TheCooler::HANDLEITMAN(int index)
{
    QComboBox * combo = qobject_cast< QComboBox * >(sender());
    if (combo == 0)
        return; // something wrong happened

    QVariant data = combo->itemData(index);
}
```

If `combo` is null, then you probably tried to call the slot by yourself, or you have connected it with a signal emitted by a class that is not a `QComboBox`.

Comment: A fair alternative, but note Qt advises [considerable caution](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qobject.html#sender) when using `sender()`.

Comment: Ho, I did not remember the warning about breaking object oriented design. But anyway, I really like the approach : being able to tell which object triggered the slot is really important in most of my Qt related developments.

Comment: In my case, sending the sender as part of the signal produces a design that's more elegant, more flexible, and easier to understand than storing the sender with the slot owner would do.  Their warning seems out of place to me.  (Anyway, none of this would matter if QComboBox would sensibly send some kind of a reference to or copy of the newly selected QVariant data as part of its selection-changed signal.  I'm only interested in simulating that missing behavior; it seems that the questioner was in the same position.)